# UIView's userInteractionEnabled property

Tags: ios, uiview

About UIView's `userInteractionEnabled` property, what Apple's doc says is:

> ...When set to NO, user events—such as touch and keyboard—intended for
>   the view are ignored and removed from the event queue. When set to
>   YES, events are delivered to the view normally...

So I have two `UIView` instances, `A` and `B`, `B` is subview of `A`, both has `userInteractionEnabled` `YES` by default.

Now I set `B` - the subview's `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, while `A`'s is `YES` and has some gesture added to `A` to respond to some user event.

If I tap the screen, according to Apple doc, this `tap event` would be ignored by `B` - the subview, since its `userInteractionEnabled` is `NO`.

But why this `tap event` would be "removed from the event queue"? I thought `A` could still capture this event according to the `responder's chain`. If the event was removed from the event queue, how could `A` capture this event?

Briefly, I would like to know whether each `UIView` instance has its own event queue?

If not, why a tap event can be captured by one view's super view after it was removed from event queue?

Or what does Apple mean by this `event queue` mentioned in the doc?

Comment: are you asking would A get the touch event or what is happening behind iOS's internal mechanism?

Comment: @mkeremkeskin I mean since event would be removed why A would get it?

Comment: As i thought you are asking iOS's internal mechanism. In pratice touch events will be removed from subview B but superview A will still get them. If you disable A then all of the view will stop listening to touch events. I think problem is Apple Doc is not clear enough. Also you can check this link http://www.programering.com/a/MjM4cjMwATE.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the crux lies in "intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue".  If you look at the Apple documentation for [Event Delivery: The Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html), it is clear that a tap event, for example, travels up that view’s chain of responders until the system finds an object that can handle it.

Intended for the view, I would see as a (touchUpInside event for example on a UIButton)

Comment: I would like to know what does Apple mean by the `event queue` mentioned in the doc

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I updated my answer, it might not answer all your questions, but I hope it shed some light :-)

Comment: If you check my post, I already mentioned `responder chain`, I am familiar with it but in my opinion `the event being removed` would be conflict with `responder chain`.